# Do I need to update Kotlin every time I work on my company's application?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, kotlin

I'm having trouble building an Android project at the company I am working for. Currently, I get a whole bunch of errors when I try to build my project due to the specified versions of the dependencies defined in the .gradle file not matching the current version of kotlin.

So, to rectify this I have updated the highlighted dependency versions in the project to match the current version of kotlin I am using.

My big question is whether I have to do this every time I want to develop on Android? I'm assuming the answers a big fat NO, but as someone completely new to this, I definitely need some help from the community if possible.

Just to explain me, we have limited development resources, hence the question on here. I'm going to be taking over the Android side of things and should probably sign up for a one-week taster course (or something like that) but for now, I have our whole Android app on our hands with minimal comments, tests or instructions.

I also posted this question to Reddit and the best advice I was given was to add a '+' to the dependencies in build.gradle instead of version numbers. I've since tried this and feel like it might not be the solution I need. This is because I feel that the live application wouldn't be working if this were the issue.

In short, I feel like my local version of the application might not be working because I have some settings in Kotlin/Android studio somewhere that I need to change.....Any suggestions you can provide RE what these settings may be would be a huge help!

Comment: Can you add what is the error you got?

Comment: sure, error:


`xecution failed for task ':V3:processProdDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
   is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.`

Answer (score 2):

The error from your comment isn't related to Kotlin. Make sure that all versions of the support library are the same, currently you're using `26.0.0-alpha1` for `customtabs` and `25.3.1` for `cardview-v7`. You should probably use version `25.3.1` for `customtabs` as well.

Also, avoid using `+`, as this makes your build always use the latest version of the dependency, which makes specific builds unreproducable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've actually re-cloned the project from github so that the original version nums are back in the build.gradle. Now I'm getting a new erropr `Failed to find target with hash string android-23 in Users/cameron/Library/Android/sdk` . 



Im assuming this means I need to download a specific android-23 module or plugin but not too sure.

Comment: Probably, yes. Did you manage to install SDK 23? Can be done using Android Studio: Tools/Android/SDK Manager.

Comment: Yes, sorted now. Needed to install the SDK and then was able to run. Now onto the errors.....